# SQLite Android и вывод данных в TextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-textview, cursor

Использую SQLite для хранения и доступа к данным в андроид-приложении. Задаю

```
public final class TaskCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {
public TaskCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
    super(cursor);
}

public Main2Activity.ObjectA getObjectA() {
    String task = getString(getColumnIndex(TestDbSchema.TestTable.Cols.TASK));
    Double answer = getDouble(getColumnIndex(TestDbSchema.TestTable.Cols.ANSWER));
    int item_id = getInt(getColumnIndex(TestDbSchema.TestTable.Cols._ID));

    Main2Activity.ObjectA O = new Main2Activity.ObjectA(new UUID(0,0));
    O.setTask(task);
    O.setAnswer(answer);

    return O;
}}
```

Для доступа к данным по выбранному ID

```
public class ObjectO {

    public TextView getObjectO() {
        TaskCursorWrapper mTaskCursorWrapper = queryTask(null, null);
        mCurrentIndex = mCurrentIndex + 1;
        mTaskCursorWrapper.moveToPosition(mCurrentIndex);
        mTaskConditionTo.setText(mTaskCursorWrapper.getObjectA().getTask());

        return mTaskConditionTo;
    }
}
```

Для вывода в текстовое поле значения из базы поля TASK пишу в OnCreate

```
ObjectO OO = new ObjectO();
    mTaskConditionTo = findViewById(R.id.view_1);
    mTaskConditionTo = OO.getObjectO();
```

Но вместо ожидаемых текстовых значений (к примеру, "Условие!") в mTaskConditionTo выводится набор каких-то цифр (к примеру, "2131492912").

Я так понимаю, ошибка в преобразовании типов. Но никак не возьму в толк, где?